# Openlayer with OpenStreetMap(OSM) as a base Layer

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, mapserver

i am getting problem to put **OpenLayer** which is coming from my Minesotta Map Server on **OSM layer** as  a Base Layer.

when i use google map as a base layer than it works fine !.

so is there possible to work as osm as a base layer and OpenLayer as overlayer.or this combonation is possible or not

Comment: OpenLayers is javascript library for visualizing mapping data. It cannot come from MapServer.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood your question...you need to set allOverlays: true
[link1](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Overlay), [link2](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/all-overlays-google.html)

```
var options = {
    projection: mercator, //EPSG:3785/900913
    displayProjection: geographic, //EPSG:4326
    theme: null,
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
    units: 'm',
    controls: [],
    numZoomLevels: MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL,
    allOverlays: true
};
OpenLayers.Util.DEFAULT_PRECISION = 18;

mp = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
```